# Aggregrate the polish if make and size are same

Tags: sql

**TableA**

```
Make    |   Size        |   Polish  |   Rough  
---------------------------------------------------------  

VG  |   2.00 up     |   2.45    |   2.7  
VG  |   2.00 up     |   3.25    |   3.5  
VG  |   1.00-1.99   |   1.20    |   1.30  
VG  |   1.00-1.99   |   1.5 |   1.6  
AG  |   0.30-0.49   |   0.35    |   0.40  
AG  |   0.50-0.99   |   0.55    |   0.60  
AG  |   0.50-0.99   |   0.65    |   0.70
```

**Output**

```
Make    |   Size        |   Polish  |   Rough  
VG  |   2.00 up     |   5.70    |   6.2   
VG  |   1.00-1.99   |   2.70    |   2.90  
AG  |   0.30-0.49   |   0.35    |   0.40  
AG  |   0.50-0.99   |   1.20    |   1.30
```

If make and size is same than polish and rough should aggregrate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select Make, Size, sum(Polish) as Polish, sum(Rough) as Rough
from TableA
group by Make, Size
```